# Why add-event-source attach a new inline policy

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-iam, aws-cdk

I'm using the AWS CDK to build the infrastructure in Python.

Step1 ~ Step4 are in the same stack.

Step 1: Create the role lambda_role with AWS managed policy `AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess` for lambda.

```
lambda_role = aws_iam.Role(self, "lambda_role", 
       assumed_by=aws_iam.ServicePrincipal("lambda.amazonaws.com"),
       role_name="lambda_role")

policy = "AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess"

lambda_role.add_managed_policy(aws_iam.ManagedPolicy.from_aws_managed_policy_name(policy))
```

Step 2: Create a table my_table and enable streams

```
stream_view_type = aws_dynamodb.StreamViewType.NEW_AND_OLD_IMAGES

my_table = aws_dynamodb.Table(self, id=tableName,
            table_name=tableName,
            partition_key=partition_key,
            stream=stream_view_type,
        )
```

Step 3: Create lambda my_lambda with lambda_role

```
my_lambda = aws_lambda.Function(self, "my_lambda"
             role=lambda_role)
```

Step 4: Set the table(my_table) as the trigger for lambda(my_lambda).

```
my_lambda.add_event_sources(
    aws_lambda_event_sources.DynamoEventSource(
         starting_position=aws_lambda.StartingPosition.LATEST,
         table=my_table,
         batch_size=table_setting["batch_size"],
         retry_attempts=table_setting["retry_attempts"],
    )
)
```

*My Question*:

1. Why Step 4 automatically create and attach the inline-policy to lambda_role? The scope of `AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess` which is created in step 1 overlaps the new created policy.
2. How to share the policy `AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess` instead of creating a new policy for each event_sources?

```
inline policy attached to lambda_role:
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": "dynamodb:ListStreams",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:dynamodb:?:?:table/my_table/stream/*",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "dynamodb:DescribeStream",
                "dynamodb:GetRecords",
                "dynamodb:GetShardIterator"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:dynamodb:?:?:table/my_table/stream/2020-07-22T03:35:56.757",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
}

Snippet of AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess attached to lambda_role:
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "dynamodb:*", ...
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*"
        }, ...
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can stop the redundant policy additions from `add_event_source` by preventing additional policy updates on your custom lambda execution role after it is created using the `Role` method: `without_policy_updates`.

To do it this way, you will also have to manually add whatever policies would have been automatically added during the lambda function initialization, since the lambda initialization won't be able to auto-update the role either. For a simple Lambda function, this would probably only be `AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole` and `AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole`.

```
lambda_role = aws_iam.Role(self, "lambda_role", 
    assumed_by=aws_iam.ServicePrincipal("lambda.amazonaws.com"),
    role_name="lambda_role",
    managed_policies=[
        aws_iam.ManagedPolicy.from_aws_managed_policy_name(
            "service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole"
        ),
        aws_iam.ManagedPolicy.from_aws_managed_policy_name(
            "service-role/AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole"
        ),
        aws_iam.ManagedPolicy.
        from_aws_managed_policy_name("AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess")
    ]
)

lambda_role = lambda_role.without_policy_updates()
my_lambda = aws_lambda.Function(self, "my_lambda"
         role=lambda_role)
```